# Flush DNS remotely output to textfile is empty

Tags: vbscript, psexec

I am trying to remotely flushdns multiple servers remotely and output the results to a textfile.  After running my script, my textfile is empty.

Script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set fso   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\servers.txt", ForReading)
Set logFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Scripts\logsssss.txt")

Do Until textFile.AtEndOfStream
hostName = textFile.Readline
Do
wshShell.run("cmd /c psexec \\" & hostName &" -u IDEALCORP\acorrera -s ipconfig /flushdns >> & hostName,TRUE")
Loop Until True
Loop
```

Any ideas why my output is blank?  What needs to be changed/modified in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are not in their place and it is better to include window style in Run method

```
NO  : wshShell.run "cmd /c psexec \\" & hostName &" -u IDEALCORP\acorrera -s ipconfig /flushdns >> & hostName,TRUE"
YES : wshShell.run "cmd /c psexec \\" & hostName &" -u IDEALCORP\acorrera -s ipconfig /flushdns >> " & hostName,0,TRUE
```

Comment: Either remove the spurious param list () or use .Run as a function.

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you hope to achieve with endlessly looping over the command for the first hostName?
2. Why don't you check the return value of the command?
3. How could logFile contain anything, if you don't write to it?
4. Did you test your command from the console?